# How does the Bible justify geocentrism?

Tags: biblical-basis, science, joshua

The Bible states in numerous places that Earth and/or man is center.

> Joshua 10:12-13: On the day the LORD gave the Amorites over to
>   Israel, Joshua said to the LORD in the presence of Israel: "O sun,
>   stand still over Gibeon, O moon, over the Valley of Aijalon." So the
>   sun stood still, and the moon stopped, till the nation avenged itself
>   on its enemies, as it is written in the Book of Jashar. The sun
>   stopped in the middle of the sky and delayed going down about a full
>   day.

Copernicus proved this false.

This error remains unresolved.

How does the Bible resolve this discrepancy?

Comment: Just for the record, Copernicus had nothing to do with proving anything useful about the solar system. He advanced a badly flawed theory that happened to put the sun in the right place, but got basically every other relevant detail badly wrong.  The person who came up with what turned out to be the correct model was Kepler, about a century later, and *actually proving it* had to wait a few more centuries.

Comment: Please [edit] this to add a quote from a Christian who says that this passage means or implies that the sun orbits the earth. We cannot research the justifications for beliefs when we don't know who are the people who believe them.

Comment: @MasonWheeler where is the evidence that heliocentrecism is wrong? Keep in mind that copernicus was one of the first to write that there was no center. He didn't just figure out the sun's non movement, but also that we were not center of anything

Comment: @curiousdannii I'm trying to keep opinions out of the mix.

Answer (score 7):

The only error here that needs resolution is your false premise and incorrect reading of the text. The Bible is not a scientific journal and includes many different literary genres. Your mistake is reading it in a way it was not meant to be read.

Even today with our advanced technical and scientific understanding of the universe, it is common to speak of "sunset"/"sunrise" and "the sun going down"/"the sun coming up". **Even in the 21st century we don't bother with the technical explanation of the earth's rotation in every day speech**, we use loose approximations based on observation from a limited perspective. To a chap standing on the ground it does kind of look like the sun is rising and setting, even if we know perfectly well about the orbit and spin of the planet.

Unless you want to assert that every modern use of terms like "sunrise" are geocentrism, then your assertion that the Bible supports geocentrism is inconsistent with the way *you* use language.

Comment: I disagree. facts are either substantiated or invalidated. The movement of the life giving force on this rock is a pretty important factor. Without that sun, none would exist. An 'all knowing' entity is expected to know this. At the very least, not get the facts wrong. Is god perfect with everything but math and astronomy? how are we defining perfection?

Comment: @boobie God didn't get anything wrong here. The only thing you disagree with is well established and documented hermeneutics. The Biblical text uses human languages exactly the way humans do and effectively (and accurately) communicates what it was intended to communicate. Just because it isn't the sort of technical documentation manual you want it to be doesn't mean it is in any way faulty.

Comment: but geocentricism is not accurate in any language. Is there a key that decodes any intended meaning?

Comment: Geocentrism is not true in any language, but in many languages, as Caleb states, there are times when it is reasonable, appropriate, and sometimes best to speak *as if it were* correct. Given the cultural understanding of astronomy at that time, it seems to me entirely appropriate to speak in such a way.